# Problems integrate jquery fullcalendar into emberjs

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, ember.js

Is it possible to get help with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLCfb/. I am trying to integrate jquery fullcalendar into emberjs but the calendar wont display. Without emberjs, thesame code displays the calendar: http://jsfiddle.net/CH4qa/.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an error. I changed:

```
App.EventView.appendTo('mycalendar');
```

to

```
App.EventView.create().appendTo('mycalendar');
```

You need to create an instance first. Check the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLCfb/4/

Comment: Thanks, I am grateful, just one last follow up question. Do you have any suggestion on why the 'title', 'start', and 'end ' are not being displayed even though handlebars template has {{title}}. I tweaked it to {{content.title}} and later {{event.title}}, but they still don't appear on the displayed calendar.